# run compatibly on/with

Tags: prepositions, collocations

I'd like to know which preposition should be used in the following sentences:

> The program runs compatibly on/with many portable devices.

> The program runs compatibly on/with this version of Windows.

> The program runs compatibly on/with the antivirus software.

Answer (score 1):

The question mixes up two expressions:  "runs on" and "is compatible with".
Rather than choosing one of the two prepositions, it might be better to separate them:

The program **runs on** portable devices.

The program **is compatible with** this version of Windows.

If the writer sees a significant difference between "running on" and "being compatible with", they should make two separate statements.

Comment: Are there no scenarios where one could use "software runs compatibly with"?

Comment: I can't imagine one where mixing the expressions would be the best choice.